# Atom beautify weird linebreaks

Tags: php, html, atom-editor, atom-beautify

I have a weird bug. When I beautify my html/php mixed code it breaks the line and puts the echo and the following tag on 2 different lines making it look ugly.

Anyone had this problem before ?

BTW look at `$answer_hash['topic_firstname']` suddenly the following `))` are green/commented looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, my only guess would be that you have softwrap (also called wordwrap) on. You can disabled it at: View -> Toggle softwrap.

To awnser your second question, the `value=""` attribute normal contains string, and not code. So it gets the green color as if it is a string.

You're using the standard syntax theme that doesn't give a color to parentesis and curly braces, so since it's in a `value=""` attribute it gets the green color.

Comment: I am indeed using the standard syntax theme. Thanks for pointing that out. Would you have any recommendations for another syntax theme ?

Comment: Altough it's mostly dependent on personal preference, I personally prefer the atom-dark syntax in combination with atom-material-ui

Answer (score 1):

It's default behavior of `PHP-CS-Fixer` (I assume you use the default PHP beautifier of `atom-beautify` in version 2) to break lines after curly braces.

> The body of each structure MUST be enclosed by braces. Braces should
>   be properly placed. Body of braces should be properly indented.
>   [Scroll down to 'braces [@PSR2, @Symfony]'](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/)

Which is defined in the [PSR-2 coding style guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/):

> Opening braces for control structures MUST go on the same line, and closing
>   braces MUST go on the next line after the body.

If you switch back to version 1 in the `atom-beautify` settings it won't do the line breaks but it stop fixing other things only available in version 2.

For completeness (although [rpm192](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8194516/rpm192)) has already answered the second part of your question: The `))` are green because the standard color for html attribute values is green. Since your document type is set to PHP, all built in functions, arrays etc. between PHP-tags are colored differently but everything else, which does not have a different color specified, keeps it's previous color (which in this case is green). As you can see in the screenshot if you place the PHP-code outside of the html attribute value the braces are colored white as usual. [image: Screenshot]

**Note:** You have more opening curly braces `{` than closing ones. Check out line 6 in my screenshot.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. The curly brace jsut wasn't visible cause i was scrolled a bit to the right. Sorry about that. Thanks for your info about the version. I'll definitly have a look at it !